# Why are the elements of this matrix as follows?

Tags: matrices

I would like to know why
$$
\hat{y} = Xb = \overbrace{X(X'X)^{-1}X'}^H y =: Hy
$$
equivalent to
$$
\hat{y}_j = \sum_{i = 1}^n h_{ji}y_i \quad
\text{with } h_{ji} = x_j'(X'X)^{-1}x_i
$$
I especially don't understand why the outer $X$ matrices become vectors and the inner matrix inverse stays the same. Moreover, why does it become $h_{ji}$ and not $h_{ij}$?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should have a look at our [basic MathJax guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to typeset math here.

Comment: As per your second question: note that if $(h_{ij}) = H$ then $(h_{ji}) = H^T$, the transpose of $H$. As @5xum suggests, this is because matrix multiplication is performed "rows times columns".

Comment: @A.P. Thank you for the added insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a matrix $A$ which has $a_{ij}$ in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column, the $j$-th value of $y=Ax$ is equal to

$$y_j = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ji}x_i.$$

This is the definition of matrix multiplication.

Now, you only need to show that in the matrix $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$, the element in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column is $h_{ij} = x_i(X'X)^{-1}x_j'$ and you are done.

Comment: Thanks you! How could I show that that is indeed the $ij$th element? I am not sure why the inverse stays the same.

Comment: @Arawer Forget about the inverse, just think about what the elements of the matrix $A\cdot B\cdot A'$ are for any pair of matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Hmmh, I find it hard to think about. Could you give any more hints? I mean, I see that it sort of makes sense to put an $i$ at the beginning and a $j$ at the end and that the transpose remains intact, but I don't really understand the specifics.

Comment: @arawer After 3 minutes, any math student would have trouble. Try it on a $3\times 3$ matrix, for example. Then, take a pencil and paper, and write the equations down. They are nasty, long, and you will make mistakes, but that's the only way to learn. You will learn nothing if I just write down the equations. Write down what the elements of $AB$ are, and multiply that with $A'$, then compare that to what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it out and I indeed now see that it is true. Problem with these kind of things is that I am always bad with memorizing identities like this, and I usually don't have time to derive them at exams. Thanks again for your your help, I appreciate it greatly!